# django - how to get all url parameters after "#"

Tags: django, url, parameters, get

How can I extract the parameters from this type of URL.

```
 "  ../oauth/#access_token=sa7a56437de94d2d351c5&token_type=score "
```

I could split by the "#" and then get all the vars, the problem is that I can't get the full url, just the part before the #.

Thank you

Comment: The part after the `#` is only being processed on the clientside, not sent the serverside.

Comment: You may consider using '?' instead of '#' and then the parameters become a GET query. Thus you could access parameters simply with     `request.GET.get("access_token")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simply cannot be done as the contents after the `#` mark are not sent to the server. You might consider adding the information after the `?` or query string.

However, if you *have* to send it, then you might consider sending a GET request using javascript. You can get the current url by `document.URL` However, you will need to make a specific URL route to handle this.

The best option is to use `?` or the query string.